# How do I get the Security Type of the currently connected WiFi network using either the BSSID or SSID?

Tags: ios, security, wifi, captivenetwork

While working on a iOS project in xcode, I use the 'CaptiveNetwork' class to retrieve the SSID, BSSID, and SSIDDATA of the currently connected WiFi network. My question is would it be possible to determine the Security Type, if any, from the given information?